# putting a condition on an includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following relationships:

```
Category has_many :posts
Post has_many :comments
Post has_many :commenters, :through => :comments
```

I have the following eager load, giving me posts, comments and commenters (note that I need all 3, and hence the includes as opposed to joins)

```
category.posts.includes(:comments, :commenters)
```

However, I'd like to limit comments (and if possible commenters) to only those created in the past two weeks while still returning the same set of posts. Initially I thought I could specify a condition on the includes:

```
category.posts.includes(:comments, :commenters).where("comments.created_at > ?", 2.weeks.ago)
```

But found that this returns only the posts that meet the condition. I'm thinking that I may need to do something like performing a subquery on comments and then performing a join. Is there an easy way to do this with AR of would I be better off doing this with sql?

Comment: If your problem is "solved" please accept the answer which solved your problem or write and accept an answer explaining how you solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to figure this out from reading this page:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

I simply needed to create an association in my Post model like:

```
Post has_many :recent_comments, :class_name = 'Comment', :conditions => ["created_at > ?", 2.weeks.ago]
```

Then I could do the following to get the desired ActiveRecord::Association object:

```
category.posts.includes(:recent_comments => :commenters)
```

There was also a suggestion of doing this by using a scope on a model. However, I read somewhere (I think it was on SO) that scopes are on their way out and that ARel has taken their place so I decided to do this without scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
category.posts.all(:includes => {:comments =>:commenters}, :conditions => ["comments.created_at = ? AND commenters.created_at = ?", 2.weeks.ago, 2.weeks.ago]
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I just needed to change the includes from includes(:comments, :commenters) to includes(:comments => :commenter) in my code. Will test it a bit more and post again if I'm having any trouble with it.

Comment: upon more testing, this doesn't quite do what I need it to. As stated in the original question, I need for posts to not be limited by the condition.

Comment: I think that I need something that will put the condition on the ON clause within the SQL query, though not sure how to do that. Alternatively, I think I can do 2 queries, one for the posts and one for the comments and commenters and find the comments that match a given post. However, I'm not yet sure how to traverse an ActiveRecord::Relation object and I'm not finding much documentation to help me.